# Importing Manually Declared Nested Schema from Package Causes NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, apache-spark-xml

I'm trying to parse XML files into DataFrames using Databricks' [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) with this line of code:

```
val xmlDF = spark
    .read
    .option("rowTag", "MeterReadingDocument")
    .option("valueTag", "foo") // meaningless, used to parse tags with no child elements
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .schema(schema)
    .xml(connectionString)
```

As you can see, I have provided a schema in order to avoid the costly operation of schema inference. This schema is defined as

```
 val schema = MyProjectUtils.Schemas.meterReadingDocumentSchema
```

Where `MyProjectUtils` is a package containing an object `Schemas` with the schema definition:

```
object Schemas {
...
// nested schemas 
...

val meterReadingDocumentSchema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("ReadingStatusRefTable", readingStatusRefTableSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("Header", headerSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("ImportExportParameters", importExportParametersSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("Channels", channelsSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("_xmlns:xsd", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("_xmlns:xsi", StringType, nullable = true)
    )
  )
}
```

You will notice the `readingStatusRefTableSchema`, `headerSchema` and other custom Schemas which are `StructTypes` corresponding to nested elements within the XML. These are in turn, nested as well, for example:

```
val headerSchema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("Creation_Datetime", creationDatetimeSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("Export_Template", exportTemplateSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("System", SystemSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("Path", pathSchema, nullable = true),
      StructField("Timezone", timezoneSchema, nullable = true)
    )
  )
```

with

```
val creationDatetimeSchema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("_Datetime", TimestampType, nullable = true),
      StructField("foo", StringType, nullable = true)
    )
  )
```

(I can provide more details on the nested nature of the schema if relevant)

If I declare these nested schemas on a notebook or as an object within the notebook I use to read data, this works and loads the data. But when I create a jar from this project and execute it, I get the following stack trace:

```
INFO ApplicationMaster [shutdown-hook-0]: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType.existsRecursively(ArrayType.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.$anonfun$existsRecursively$1(StructType.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.$anonfun$existsRecursively$1$adapted(StructType.scala:508)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.prefixLengthImpl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.exists(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.exists$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.exists(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.existsRecursively(StructType.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.$anonfun$existsRecursively$1(StructType.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.$anonfun$existsRecursively$1$adapted(StructType.scala:508)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.prefixLengthImpl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.exists(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.exists$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.exists(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.existsRecursively(StructType.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharUtils$.hasCharVarchar(CharVarcharUtils.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharUtils$.failIfHasCharVarchar(CharVarcharUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema(DataFrameReader.scala:76)
    at com.mycompany.DataIngestion$.delayedEndpoint$com$mycompany$DataIngestion$1(DataIngestion.scala:44)
    at com.mycompany.DataIngestion$delayedInit$body.apply(DataIngestion.scala:10)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at com.mycompany.DataIngestion$.main(DataIngestion.scala:10)
    at com.mycompany.DataIngestion.main(DataIngestion.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:739)
)
```

I added another simpler csv file and created a schema for it in the `Schemas` object. This schema has no nested structs from the same `Schemas` object and writing.

```
 val simplerDocSchema = MyProjectUtils.Schemas.anotherDocSchema

spark
      .read
      .csv(path)
      .schema(simplerDocSchema)
      .load(connectionString)
```

```
Schemas {
 ...
val anotherDocSchema: StructType = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("ID", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("DATE", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("CODE", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("AD", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("ACCOUNT", StringType, nullable = true)
    )
  )
}
```

I expected this to fail as well but ran OK in a compiled project as well as in a notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't state which Spark version you are using the code doesn't seem to have [changed for 8 years](https://github.com/apache/spark/blame/branch-3.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/ArrayType.scala#L105):

```
override private[spark] def existsRecursively(f: (DataType) => Boolean): Boolean = {
    f(this) || elementType.existsRecursively(f)
  }
```

Highly probably elementType is null.  As you don't provide the whole code I'd guess you have an ArrayType(someVal, ..) which is not yet defined.

Swap your vals to def's and try again.

Comment: But if it weren't defined the compiler would be showing an error, and it does not. 

How would it be different if using def instead of val?

Comment: evaluation order, did you try it?

Comment: It did indeed work, I had a schema that was defined just below where it was used and that compiles fine but it seems that it might throw Spark off at execution time. Changing val to def solved that. Thanks!